# Proper management of database resources: cursor and connection

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, flask, flask-restful, pymysql

I am creating a test Flask API, and have created a `Database` class that I use from my main app. I am using `pymysql` to access my MySQL DB but I am having trouble figuring out when to close the cursor and connection. Right now I have

```
import pymysql

class Database:
    def __init__(self):
        host = '127.0.0.1'
        user = 'root'
        password = ''
        db = 'API'

        self.con = pymysql.connect(host=host, user=user, password=password, db=db, cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor, autocommit=True)
        self.cur = self.con.cursor()

    def getUser(self, id):
        sql = 'SELECT * from users where id = %d'
        self.cur.execute(sql, (id))
        result = self.cur.fetchall()
        return result

    def getAllUsers(self):
        sql = 'SELECT * from users'
        self.cur.execute(sql)
        result = self.cur.fetchall()
        return result

    def AddUser(self, firstName, lastName, email):
        sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`firstName`, `lastName`, `email`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
        self.cur.execute(sql, (firstName, lastName, email))
```

I have tried adding `self.cur.close()` and `self.con.close()` after each execution of the cursor in the functions but then I get an error the next time I call a function saying the cursor is closed, or after I do an insert statement it won't show the new value even though it was inserted correctly into MySQL. How do I know when to close the cursor, and how to start it back up properly with each call to a method?

Comment: Did my answer make sense?

Comment: @NathanWright yes, thank you!

Comment: Np glad it helped

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds like a great use case for a python [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html). Context Managers allow you to **properly manage resources**, such as a database connection, by *allowing you to specify how your resource's set-up and tear down methods should work*. You can create your own custom context manager in one of two ways: First, by wrapping your database class, and implementing the required methods for the context manager: `__init__()`, `__enter__()`, and `__exit__()`. Second, by utilizing a `@contextmanager` decorator on a function definition and creating a generator for your database resource within said function definition. I will show both approaches and let you decide which one is your preference. The `__init__()` method is the ***initialization method*** for your custom context manager, similar to the initialization method used for custom python classes. The `__enter__()` method is your ***setup code*** for your custom context manager. Lastly, the `__exit()__` method is your ***teardown*** code for your custom context manager. **Both approaches utilize these methods** with the main difference being the first method will explicitly state these methods within your class definition. Where as in the second approach, all the code up to your generator's `yield` statement is your *initialization and setup code* and all the code *after the `yield` statement is your teardown code.* I would also consider extracting out your user based database actions into a user model class as well. Something along the lines of:

custom context manager: (**class based approach**):

```
import pymysql

class MyDatabase():
    def __init__(self):
        self.host = '127.0.0.1'
        self.user = 'root'
        self.password = ''
        self.db = 'API'

        self.con = None
        self.cur = None

    def __enter__(self):
        # connect to database
        self.con = pymysql.connect(host=self.host, user=self.user, password=self.password, db=self.db, cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor, autocommit=True)
        self.cur = self.con.cursor()
        return self.cur

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, traceback):
        # params after self are for dealing with exceptions
        self.con.close()
```

**user.py (refactored)**:'

```
# import your custom context manager created from the step above
# if you called your custom context manager file my_database.py: from my_database import MyDatabase

import <custom_context_manager>

class User:
    def getUser(self, id):
        sql = 'SELECT * from users where id = %d'
        with MyDatabase() as db: 
            db.execute(sql, (id))
            result = db.fetchall()

        return result

    def getAllUsers(self):
        sql = 'SELECT * from users'
        with MyDatabase() as db: 
            db.execute(sql)
            result = db.fetchall()
        return result

    def AddUser(self, firstName, lastName, email):
        sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`firstName`, `lastName`, `email`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
        with MyDatabase() as db:
            db.execute(sql, (firstName, lastName, email))
```

context manager **(decorator approach)**:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import pymysql


@contextmanager
def my_database():
    try:
        host = '127.0.0.1'
        user = 'root'
        password = ''
        db = 'API'
        con = pymysql.connect(host=host, user=user, password=password, db=db, cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor, autocommit=True)
        cur = con.cursor()
        yield cur
    finally:
        con.close()
```

Then within your `User` class you could use the context manager by first importing the file and then using it similar to as before:

```
with my_database() as db:
   sql = <whatever sql stmt you wish to execute>
   #db action 
   db.execute(sql)
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Any reason why you are not closing the cursor object?